# Jquery code won't modify attributes of html tag on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Can someone please tell me why the next jquery code is not working. I already  tried it outside the `$(document).ready` block and that also don't work

note: the weird "{{ }}" and "{% %}", is typically django

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".post_thumb_up").hover(function () {
        $(".post_thumb_up").attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up_hover.png");
    });

    $(".post_thumb_up").click(function () {
        $(".post_thumb_up").attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up.png");
    });

});
```

html:

```
    <div class="post">
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <img class="post_image" src="{% static post.image_path %}">
        <p><i>Door: {{ post.author }}<br>Datum: {{ post.date_posted|date:"l d F, Y, H:i" }}</i></p>
        <div class="post_line"></div>
        <div class="post_actions">
            <input id="test" type="image" class="post_thumb_up" src="{% static "media/thumb_up.png" %}">
            <input type="image" class="post_thumb_down" src="{% static "media/thumb_down.png" %}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How is _"...is not working"_ defined? -> [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event which is Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on(".post_thumb_up", 'hover', function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up_hover.png");
    });

    $(document).on(".post_thumb_up", 'click', function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up.png");
    });

});
```

Comment: Why should OP use `.on()` instead of `.click()`/`.hover()` (which themselves just call `.on()`)?

Comment: @Andreas this content come from ajax as Jake said. so click and hover event need to bind. that time .on() have to use.

Comment: _"...as Jake said"_ - In one of his comments on another answer which he added hours after your answer. Please edit your answer so it not only says _"use X"_ but instead _"because of X you have to use Y"_ with a real explanation of _X_ and _Y_

Answer (score 0):

is your div(.post) template part part of SSR markup? If it's being generated dynamically then you need to bind event post its render.

I suspect that might be a case.

Comment: Yes, this template is server side rendered and I call this template with an Ajax call, but what do you mean by "then you need to bind event post its render.".

Comment: So here is the solution now.  As this template is achieved via Ajax call, so on success of Ajax , you might be injecting this on the Dom. So once it is injected over Dom , you can bind event on  newly injected DOM nodes.

Comment: Or 2nd solution: you can you jquery event delegation as well using document as root node. which will help in binding events to dynamic nodes which we get through Ajax or created after Ajax.

Comment: Oke I googled a bit, i Will try it with ```.bind```. When I'm home.

Comment: @Jake _"...with an Ajax call"_ - This information **has** to be part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

### try to use  setTimeout

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".post_thumb_up").hover(function () {
       // may be you need to set "http://" or "fullpath" to src value
        $(this).attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up_hover.png");
    });

    $(".post_thumb_up").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/post_it/static/media/thumb_up.png");
    });
  },200)
});
```